# nginx 301 redirect with query_string variable and if

Tags: redirect, nginx

I'm new to nginx and I need to setup up a load of 301 redirects each pointing old files to the new ones, like this:

```
# www.domain.com/products/category/product.php?id=103 
# to 
# www.domain.com/products/new-category-name/new-product-name.html
```

To deal with the `?` I have the following which seems to be working fine:

```
if ($args ~ "id=103") {
    rewrite ^ /products/new-category-name/new-product-name.html? permanent;
}
```

How does this look? I'm aware that `if` is mostly a bad idea in nginx but I don't fully understand why. Is the above rule okay? it seems to work fine. Lastly, I have around 100 of these urls to redirect. Will it be okay to just duplicate this rule for each url?

Thanks

---

**UPDATE**
The mapping looks to be a great solution but I'm not sure where to place the code. I currently have the following:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @modx-rewrite;
}
```

It's stated that any additional rules need to be placed before this location block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would sugguest to use the ngx_http_map_module

create a file for the urlmapping, that contains old and new urls, like

```
/products/category/product.php?id=103    /products/new-category-name/new-product-name.html ;
/products/category2/product.php?id=104   /products/new-category2-name/new-product104-name.html ;
```

that's easy to maintain. just add a new line for a new mapping and reload your nginx config.

in your nginx config create a location with a mapping like

```
map $request_uri $newuri {
    include /path/to/your/mappingfile;
}
server {
    ...
    location / {
        if ($newuri) {
            return 301 $newuri;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a good idea, but the map directive will need to be outside of the server block.

Comment: This looks great but I'm not sure where to place it. I've updated my question with more information, thanks

Comment: Thanks so much @hzei unfortunately I don't have access to outside the server block so I can't use this solution. I've set it as the accepted answer though as it otherwise looks perfect. I'm open to other suggestions.